# Storing data in a hexagonal grid for word search Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, grid, hex

newbie to Python. I would like to know how to store letters in a hexagonal grid. I tried using  graph but I do not understand it too well. The first letter (from a file or something) goes to the center hexagonal box of the honeycomb structure, and the next set of letters(6) would fill in outside it, and so on. Thanks.

`If the letters are ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], then a goes to the center hex and b to g fill in the outside hex grids in clockwise direction.`

In clearer terms, the letters are from A to S. The purpose is to store the same in a hexagonal honeycomb structure, with a in the center, (b,c,d,e,f,g) outside it, (h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s) outside it and so on.

Comment: This question is painful to read, and getting a lot of downvotes, because it is very unclear what you wish to do, and you have not provided an attempt to solve your own problem.

Comment: Python does not have a "hexagonal grid" data structure or container. When you say you would like to store letters in a hexagonal grid, what do you *mean*? What does "I tried using graph" mean...?

Comment: @RickTeachey : The letters are from a to s. The purpose is to store the same in a hexagonal honeycomb structure, with a in the center, (b,c,d,e,f,g) outside it, (h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s) outside it and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you mean by "hexagonal grid". But here's an attempt at a solution anyway. EDIT: Ok, what you want is much clearer now. The below solution should work.

I will assume that you want your data held in some kind of data structure that represents a geometrical hexagonal grid. A hexagonal grid consists of a single central hexagon surrounded by 6 hexagons, which are in turn surrounded by 12 hexagons, then 18, etc etc.

We can represent this geometrical structure using a list of lists:

```
[['a'], ['b','c','d','e','f','g'], ['h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s']]
```

The length of the first list is 1, the second 6, etc etc. You can access each "level" of the honeycomb, and then the letter in that level, this way (note that indices begin with zero, not 1):

```
my_honeycomb[0][0] # 'a'
my_honeycomb[2][3] # 'k'
my_honeycomb[1][7] # IndexError
```

The third statement produces an index error because for that level, index 7 doesn't exist.

One way to load your honeycomb structure is using the `input()` function:

```
my_honeycomb = [[]] # a list containing an empty list
level = 0
ind = 0
for letter in input('Enter your string:\n\n\t'):
    if ind > level * 6: # check if index is valid for this level 
        level += 1
        ind = 1
        my_honeycomb.append([]) # go to the next level
    my_honeycomb[level].append(letter) # add letter to current level
    ind += 1 # advance to next index
```

Comment: Assuming that the data is in this form, `['A', 'BCDEFG', ....]`, how do I go about it? Apart from changing the for condition? Thanks.

Comment: You can just do `for letter in ''.join(['a', 'bcdefg']:`and otherwise keep the same script as above. If you want to iterate through that list, you'll have to adjust the script.